# How to save data in a separate database

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm new here. I am currently enrolled in a Data Analytics degree program. I looked through the past questions but I could not find an answer to my question.

Here is my question.  Let's say you have a plain and simple HTML form on a webpage. Each field is connected to a certain column on the database, correct? Like your first name and last name.

What if someone wanted to store the username and password on it's own separate database on a completely different server. How does the software know to send those form fields to a completely different database? Does it work off of IP? I'm really confused as to how this is accomplished.

Comment: Not necessary Field is directly connected to database, The webpage just collects  inputs. Where data get inserted is depend on configured database connection. If you have to insert data into different server then you need to change the connection string.

Comment: The form data on the HTML page is sent to the web server through an HTTP request. The web application then processes this request and typically uses a connection string (which includes information about the database) to connect to the database and update the database appropriately. The connection string can use either hostname or IP address, but hostname is typically used as it is more human readable. When one wants the application to send data to a different database, they can just modify the connection string. This is typically done during web app development when switching environments.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very high-level summary of what happens but hopefully it makes sense.
When the user submits the form, the form data on the HTML page is sent to the web server through an HTTP request. The web application then processes this request and typically uses a connection string (which includes information about the database) to connect to the database and update the database appropriately. Each field in the form does not have to be directly associated with a field in the database. For example, the application may be coded so that multiple fields are concatenated into one database column. The connection string can use either hostname or IP address, but hostname is typically used as it is more human readable. 
When one wants the application to send data to a different database, they can just modify the connection string. This is typically done during web app development when switching environments. For example, in the attached diagram, if I wanted to use the production database instead of the test database I could modify the connection string within the web application so that it is pointed to the production database by simply changing the hostname in the connection string.

[image: Diagram of Web Application]